# Source configuration file avoiding any execution

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working on a program to process requests in bash which are requested by users in a WebInterface. To give users flexibility they can specify several parameters per each job, at the end the request is saved in a file with a specific name, so the bash script could perform the requested task.

This file at the end is filled like this:

```
ENVIRONMENT="PRO"
INTEGRATION="J050_provisioning"
FILE="*"
DIRECTORY="out"
```

So the bash script will source this file to perform the needed tasks user requested. And it works great so far, but I see a security issue with this, if user enters malicious data, something like:

```
SOMEVAR="GONNAHACK $(rm -f some_important_file)"
OTHERVAR="DANGEROUZZZZZZ `while :; do sleep 10 & done`"
```

This will cause undesirable effects when sourcing the file :). Is there a way to prevent a source file execute any code but variable initializations? Or the only way would be just *grep* the source file before sourcing it to check it is not dangerous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do not source it. Make it a configuration file composed of `name=value` lines (without the double quotes), read each name/value pair and assign value to name. In order not to overwrite critical variables like `PATH`, prefix the name with `CONF_` for example.

Crude code:

```
while IFS='=' read -r conf_name conf_value; do
    printf -v "CONF_$conf_name" '%s' "$conf_value" \
    || echo "Invalid configuration name '$conf_name'" >&2
done < your_configuration_file.conf
```

Test it works:

```
$ echo "${!CONF_*}"
CONF_DIRECTORY CONF_ENVIRONMENT CONF_FILE CONF_INTEGRATION CONF_OTHERVAR CONF_SOMEVAR

$ printf '%s\n' "$CONF_SOMEVAR"
GONNAHACK $(rm -f some_important_file)
```